# How to color given data with matplotlib python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I took Machine Learning course but since I have no idea about ML, it is very hard for me to understand all concept. I have a homework and I have to plot data to be able to start homework but I couldn't even plot the data properly. For question, instructor sent us a csv data file which consists of 3 columns. 3rd column shows data class either blue or red. But I didn't understand how to use it. Question is in below:

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGuZc.png)

I tried to plot data but I got this result:

[image]

My code is like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv('Question1.csv')
X = list(df.iloc[:,0])
y = list(df.iloc[:,1])
X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

plt.plot(X,y,'.' )
plt.plot()
```

You can see and download data set from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W5FcGv3IGqhj_n5ppe6Qy0byNgvzuWXU/view?usp=share_link).

Could someone help me to classify data, please?

I couldn't try anyhing cause I didn't understand anything about question.

Comment: You're not just coloring these points on a plot, you're building a logistic regression model that will learn the data in that CSV file and then be able to classify them into 2 different categories (orange and blues). Those figures are just visualizations showing the classifying power of the model you are supposed to build. And the red/blue backgrounds are just boundaries that decide which category a point belongs to. I suggest you read more on the processes that occur in ML as you seem to lack the basics of ML (data prep, model training, testing, output visualization).

Comment: Also, no one on StackOverflow will do your homework for you, plus you should understand what's happening in the exercise to learn, otherwise just applying a solution without understanding it won't be helpful to you and you won't learn much from your ML course.

Comment: I wasn't expecting from anyone to do my homework. I already asked my question about how to plot data. It is only begining of the homework. Take a chill pill.

Comment: Welcome to SO, @AnnaDewitt ! I think Adam was mislead because you asked to help you _classify_ the data, which would be done with a model. Whereas you probably intended to ask for help to _display_ the data with its classes

Comment: @AnnaDewitt Sorry it's my bad, I thought you hadn't classified your data yet as Ciprian mentioned and you were asking for help on how to train a model to classify it. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

Your data looks very similar to the picture, so you're close :).

What you can do, it to use pandas to filter the dots by their colour, and make two calls to plot. You can pass the color to plot with, so in the first call you'd pass 'blue' and in the second call, with the 2nd set of points, you'd use `yellow` for the color.

I think you could use `scatter` rather than `plot`, since that one is made for points, whereas `plot` is for lines. Yours is similar because you've used `.` as the line type, but `scatter` is the tool for the job.